# Infinix Hot 8 bricked. No OS, No recovery

Tags: unbricking, infinix

I think I bricked my Infinix Hot 8 X650C. I have no OS installed and no Recovery Mode installed. Also, fastboot and adb can't recognise my device on PC.

What to do?

Comment: Your phone is a Mediatek based phone. Often these phones are flashed when switched off using a special software. Check xda developer forum and this site for Mediatek flashing.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/infinix-hot-8-x650c-root-twrp-un-bricking-custom-rom.3986799

Comment: Download the stock rom for your device model. Since this has Mediatek chipset, please learn a little bit about [mtkclient(i highly recommend this for MediaTek processors)](https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient).